# TypeError: androlyze_main() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python-3.x, androguard

When I use androlyze.py [apk], I receive a Error:TypeError: androlyze_main() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

I'm using androguard in mac with python environment, I use "pip3 install androguard" to install androguard, but when I run `androlyze.py /Users/zhangxu/Downloads/UCarNew-debug.apk`
It return the error.

```
zhangxudeMacBook-Pro:androguard zhangxu$ androlyze.py /Users/zhangxu/Downloads/UCarNew-debug.apk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/androlyze.py", line 47, in <module>
    androlyze_main(args.debug, args.ddebug, args.no_session, args.apk)
TypeError: androlyze_main() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I have google, but no gain; Anyone can help me solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution. I run `androguard analyze` command， and I find the `<function androguard.cli.main.androlyze_main(session, filename)>`，`androlyze_main()` method just has two argument,but the `androlyze.py` file use `androlyze_main(args.debug, args.ddebug, args.no_session, args.apk)` .

You can see this:[androguard issue](https://github.com/androguard/androguard/issues/668)

Comment: You can also use `androguard analyze` command come into ishell install of `androlyze.py -s`